# Type mismatch Error / Privat Sub / VBA 32-bit and 64-bit

Tags: vba

since I have relatively little experience with VBA programming, I hope that you might be able to help me. I have the following problem. We use a script that is only designed for 32 bit but does not work on 64 bit "PrtSafe Error". I have adjusted my code accordingly and now I keep getting a Type Mismatch Error when ** Private Sub getRawDataByMatDate () ** is shown highlighted in yellow. What could be the problem? See code:

````
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    '64 bit declares here
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
   "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    '32 bit declares here
Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
   "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
#End If
```

' Gibt angemeldeten Benutzernamen zurück
Private Function getCurrentUsername()


        Dim Retval As Long
        Dim Puffer As String * 256
        Dim UserName As String


    Retval = GetUserName(Puffer, Len(Puffer))
    
    ' Bei vbNullChar "abtrennen" und anzeigen
    If Retval <> 0 Then
        UserName = Left$(Puffer, InStr(1, Puffer, vbNullChar) - 1)
        getCurrentUsername = UserName
    Else
        getCurrentUsername = ""
    End If
    
End Function


**Mismatch Type error**

' Holt Rohdaten aus DB. Die Abfragekriterien sind Materialnummer
' und Start und Enddatum. Verwendet Stored Procedures:
' proc_BTG_GeRawDataByMatChrg, proc_BTG_GeRawDataByMat
```
Private Sub getRawDataByMatDate() 

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sQuery As String

    Dim row As Integer, iCountRecords As Integer
    Dim rec As Integer, rowOutput As Integer
    Dim sMatnr As String, sDateFrom As String, sDateTo As String
    Dim sDB As String
    
    rowOutput = ROW_OUTPUT_START
    iCountRecords = 0
    
    MsgBox "date"
    
    For row = ROW_BEREICH_START To ROW_BEREICH_END ' über abzufragende Mat, chrgnr.
        sMatnr = Cells(row, COL_MATNR).Value ' eingaben von Tabelle
        sDateFrom = Range(RANGE_DATE_FROM).Value
        sDateTo = Range(RANGE_DATE_TO).Value
        
        If sMatnr <> "" Then
        
            sQuery = "exec " + PROC_GETRAWDATABYMATDATE + " " + sMatnr + _
                        ",'" + sDateFrom + "','" + sDateTo + "'"
            Set rs = conn.Execute(sQuery)
            
            ' recordset auf tabelle kopieren, feld obenlinks wird angegeben
            Call Cells(rowOutput, COL_OUT_MATNR).CopyFromRecordset(rs)
            
            iCountRecords = iCountRecords + rs.RecordCount
            rowOutput = rowOutput + rs.RecordCount ' erste Zeile für nächste abfrage
                
        End If
            
    Next row
    
    ' Anzahl Datensätze ausgeben
    Range(RANGE_COUNT_RECORDS).Value = CStr(iCountRecords) + " Datensätze"

End Sub
````

Comment: **(a)** You can get the username much simpler with `environ("username")`. **(b)** I don't think your problem is related to the `getCurrentUsername` - function. **(c)** you are using unqualified ranges - are you sure you want to work always on  `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: I get a compile error on the "```" but for the rest it's working on my 64b machine.

Comment: Basically, the VBA application reads data from an SQL database and reports back to an Excel sheet. The DB itself is on a Windows Server 2003. Is it due to a problem similar to that in this article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729023/type-mismatch-error-on-adodb-recordset

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-type-mismatch-error-message-when-you-run-a-vba-macro-in-a-64-bit-version-of-an-office-2010-application-ba8aae20-0762-4108-93de-1787f6e09076

Comment: Is it possibly due to Windows Server 2003. As I understand it, only 32 bit system is running under Windows 2003 Server

Comment: But your office is not running on the Server?!

Comment: That's right, of course, the Office doesn't run on Windows Server 2003. Could the hotfix solve the problem?